# How to empty Bot About field of telegram bot through Bot Father

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I would like to empty bot about field of my Telegram Bot, however when I use Bot Father to edit the field I can neither send an empty input nor space(s). Is there a command to do so or any other workarounds?

I tried to find some kind of `/empty` command or send Bot Father a space character but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to empty the About field of a Telegram Bot.

---

Quoting from the [bots features](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#about-text-description-and-profile-media) page:

> ##### About text, description and profile media
>
> When new users open your bot, they will be met with a helpful description in a box titled “What can this bot do?”.
>
> ...
>
> **Once set**, the description, **about text** and profile pic can be replaced **but never fully removed**.